# Работа с несколькими DataSource в пределах одного отчета

Tags: devexpress

помогите пожалуйста. Второй день копаю и ничего не могу решить.
Проблема такая.
DevExpress/Winforms

Задача построить отчет с несколькими таблицами.
Условно в отчете должны быть две таблицы  со списком  ручек и тетрадок.

Данные в отчет нужно передавать объектом класса.

Что я делаю:
1.Создал класс

```
 class MyLiitleWarehouse
{
    public string shiftKey { get; set; }
    public string dateTime { get; set; }
    public string count { get; set; }
    public List<Books> BooksItems{ get; set; }
    public List<Pens> PensItems{ get; set; }

}

 class Books
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string bookName{ get; set; }
    public string pageCount{ get; set; }

}


  class Pens
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string color{ get; set; }
    public string matireal{ get; set; }

}
```

2. В дизайнере создал шаблон отчета(.repx) и сохранил в отдельную папку
3. Настало время смотреть отчет

   ```
       List<MyLiitleWarehouse> data = new List<MyLiitleWarehouse>();
         ///заполним его//
        XtraReport report = new XtraReport();
        string APP_PATH = Application.StartupPath;
        report.LoadLayout(APP_PATH+@"/repx/MyLittleReport.repx");
        report.DataSource = data;
        report.ShowPreview();
   ```

4.Результат

В дизайнере отчетов есть пункт "Элемент данных" и выбрать можно только один

```
 public List<Books> BooksItems{ get; set; }
 или
 public List<Pens> PensItems{ get; set; }
```

Соответственно в таблице отчета полный список либо ручек либо книжек.

Попробовал вместо MyLiitleWarehouse добавить несколько DataSource Books и Pens  в дизайнере отчетов.
Тогда  можно выбрать "Элемент данных" для каждой из них, но возникает вопрос
как тут назначить несколько DataSource

```
 report.LoadLayout(APP_PATH+@"/repx/MyLittleReport.repx");
        report.DataSource = data;
```

PS

Искал как мог, на оффсайте тоже ничего нет, выручайте товарищи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снят, решением оказалось Создание детализированных секций в дизайнере отчета.
При создании "детальной" секции можно выбрать элемент данных для нее.
В таком случае можно просто засылать один класс как я делал в самом начале

```
  List<MyLiitleWarehouse> data = new List<MyLiitleWarehouse>();
```